# How To Get Last Word From Caret Position In JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, string, indexof, caret

I am using pure JavaScript and I want to get the last word where my current caret position is from the text string  in a variable as shown in the below image, I want to get the `unknown` word.

[image]

In C#, I used the below code concept and its working there perfectly...

```
private static char[] splitters = new char[] { ' ', '\n', '۔' };
int caretPosition = string.SelectionStart;
string tempLastWord = string.Substring(0, caretPosition);
string lastWord = tempLastWord.Substring(tempLastWord.LastIndexOfAny(splitters) + 1);
```

Now I want to do the same in the pure JavaScript as below...

```
var splitters =  [ ' ', '\n', '۔' ];
var caretPosition = document.getElementById(Desired_ID).value.slice(0, document.getElementById(Desired_ID).selectionStart).length;
var tempLastWord = document.getElementById(Desired_ID).value.substring(0, caretPosition);
var lastWord = tempLastWord.substring(tempLastWord.lastIndexOf(splitters) + 1);
```

But my JavaScript code is not working perfectly. Can anyone help me...???

Comment: You are missing a closing parentehesis in the last line: `tempLastWord.lastIndexOf(splitters) + 1`

Comment: Also, I'm not sure lastIndexOf in javaScript can take an array as a parameter. You may need to call it separately for each delimiter and then pick the max result.

Comment: @LiborV, Thanks for the little mistake actually it was missed here. And yes, JavaScript only contain `string.lastIndexOf(searchvalue,start)` only not accepting any array that's why asking for any alternative...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var lastWord = tempLastWord.substring(tempLastWord.lastIndexOf('\n') + 1);
lastWord = lastWord.substring(lastWord.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
lastWord = lastWord.substring(lastWord.lastIndexOf('?') + 1);
```

This works.

Answer (score 0):

var lastWord = tempLastWord.substring(tempLastWord.lastIndexOf(splitters + 1));

Comment: In JavaScript, the function is `string.lastIndexOf(searchvalue,start)` and its not accepting any arrays...